# MS Excel: Randomize column of strings into a grid of strings

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a MS Excel sheet with 100 names in a single column.

On another sheet, I have a 10 x 10 grid of cells from which I want to randomly assign a name from the column.

Is there a relatively easy way to achieve this, or will it involve VBA type work?

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with a helper column that creates a random order number from 1 to 100.  With your names in A2:A101.  In B2 put:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($1:$100)/(COUNTIFS($B$1:B1,ROW($1:$100))=0),RANDBETWEEN(1,100-COUNT($B$1:B1)))
```

And copy down.

This will randomly select a number between 1 and 100 with the k, in the AGGREGATE being `RANDBETWEEN(1,100-COUNT($B$1:B1))`. While the `COUNTIFS($B$1:B1,ROW($1:$100))=0` makes sure we do not get duplicates.

[image]

Then we use INDEX/MATCH to find the value.  Put this in the upper right corner of the grid:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,MATCH((ROW($A1)-1)*10+COLUMN(A$1),$B:$B,0))
```

As is it drug over and down it looks for 1-10 in the first row and 11-20 in the second and so on.  And since the lookup column is randomized it will be random.

Then copy over 10 and down 10:

[image]

---

If one has office 365 Excel then the INDEX/MATCH can be replaced with this dynamic version that will spill the 10x10 automatically:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(SEQUENCE(10,10),B:B,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the names are stored in column A:

1. In the column B, apply the formula `=RAND()`
2. Copy and paste the resulting values into column B, overwriting the formula
3. In column C, apply the formula `=RANK(B2, $B$2:$B$101)`. This will enable you to assign a number 1-100 to each name
4. Above your 10x10 grid, add the numbers 1-10. Do the same to the left of your 10x10 grid. These will serve as your row and column headers.

Now, assuming your row headers are in `E2:E11` and your column headers are in `F1:O1`...

5. Enter the formula `=INDEX($A$2:$A$101, MATCH(($E2-1)*10+F$1, $C$2:$C$101,0))` into cell F2 and drag across 10x10 grid

[image: Example solution]

Answer (score 0):

Try this array formula and end with **Shift+ Ctrl + Enter**:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$10,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA($A$1:$A$10)))
```

[image]